# VS2010 Chart Control: Reduce Y-Axis Margin

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

How do I reduce the width of the left margin area shown below, marked in red?

[image]

Comment: Related thing I'm wondering: How to at least make that margin constant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

Chart.ChartAreas(Chart_ChartArea_ObjectName).InnerPlotPosition = New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ElementPosition(3, -2, 94, 96)

Use the GUI property window to get the values right.

Answer (score 0):

Me.Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(m_x_reduce, m_y_reduce)