# VS2010 Chart Control (MSChart) fixed margin Y Axis Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, controls, mschart

Depending on the values beeing displayed on the Y-Axis, the position of the Y-Axis is not always the same. I'd like to tell the Y-Axis somehow a fixed size for the labelwidth (lets say 30 Pixels) so the Y-Axis doesnt "jump" around anymore and becomes independent from the width of the Labels. Is that possible?

[image]

you can see three different margins:

- If Y-Axis is displaying values 1-40
- If the Y-Axis is displaying values 1-8
- If the Y-Axis is displaying values 0-1.2

(So far I've found only this how to reduce a margin, but this is another margin:
[VS2010 Chart Control: Reduce Y-Axis Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071246/vs2010-chart-control-reduce-y-axis-margin))

Comment: In the meantime I got my question answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/visualcsharpde/thread/749a11d7-201f-491c-9f18-6cda60f50089/#2fd85736-e6e1-4de6-8b2f-4a7909552db2 (in german, but might still help somebody out someday...)